# How To Get Hours Since Last Webpage Visit In Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, web, html

How do I go about displaying the amount of hours since the last time the user visited the webpage? I want to do this in Javascript preferably, but JQuery is fine too.

Comment: You can't possibly do that with client side script. At least for a long term. Try storing the time in your server for that.

Comment: You can store the last visit time as a cookie then read from it and do some math to figure it out.

Comment: You just answered your own question if you want to do it client side.

Comment: @Woowing what if the user uses another browser/computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have [`getCookie` and `setCookie` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript):

```
const lastVisit = getCookie('lastVisitTime');
const now = Date.now();
if (lastVisit) {
   const hoursSinceLastTime = Math.ceil((parseInt(lastVisit) - now) / 3600);
   alert(`It's been ${hoursSinceLastTime} hour(s) since you last visited us.`);
}
setCookie('lastVisitTime', now);
```

Comment: So do I just paste this in a script tag and it should work?

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything straight away.

Comment: It will work if you have the corresponding `setCookie` (3-arity usually) and `getCookie` functions. I linked you a stack overflow question with many implementations to chose from.

Comment: Thank you! I tweaked its design and now it works perfectly!